# firestore data get multiple id's and get that id's details in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("Users").doc(auth.uid).collection("Posts").get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    setList(
      snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => {
          db.collection('Users').where("id", "==", doc.data().frd_id).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot?.docs.map((doc) => {
              doc.data()
            })
          })
        )
      })
  })
```

single data only add into the state

the output expecting multiple id's details get into state

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to load every `frd_id` separately, your `setList` actually doesn't put any of that data into the state, as the data is still being loaded asynchronously.

You'll want to first load all the posts, and only then set them to the state.